# Is there a way to embed one code snippet into another?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, embed, code-snippets

Let's assume that I have

- *snippet A*
- *snippet B*
  **where** *snippet A* **contains** *snippet B n times* **with** *n > 1*.

Right now I have copied the content of *snippet B* into *snippet A*. This has the disadvantage, that whenever I change *snippet B*, I have to additionally change *snippet A*. Therefore, my question is whether there is some kind of statement to embed one snippet into another?
e.g.
 `<externalsnippet src=".\snippetB.snippet" />`
 or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

**You could use an external parsed general entity** to declare an entity reference for *snippet B* and then use it n number of times inside of snippet A.

When snippet A is parsed, the entity references will be expanded and the content from snippet B will be included at each spot where the entity was used.

**For example, assume that you had a file called snipppetB.xml:**

```
<snippetB>
  <foo>Content goes here</foo>
</snippetB>
```

**And a file for *snippet A* declared an entity called `snippetB` referencing snippetB.xml and used it four times:**

```
<!DOCTYPE snippetA [
   <!ENTITY snippetB SYSTEM "./snippetB.xml">
]>
<snippetA>
<a>&snippetB;</a>
<b>&snippetB;</b>
<c>&snippetB;</c>
<d>&snippetB;</d>
</snippetA>
```

**When snippetA.xml is parsed, the XML content would look like this:**

```
 <snippetA>
 <a>
 <snippetB>
  <foo>Content goes here</foo> 
  </snippetB>
  </a>
 <b>
 <snippetB>
  <foo>Content goes here</foo> 
  </snippetB>
  </b>
 <c>
 <snippetB>
  <foo>Content goes here</foo> 
  </snippetB>
  </c>
 <d>
 <snippetB>
  <foo>Content goes here</foo> 
  </snippetB>
  </d>
  </snippetA>
```